# how to break the string of 100000+ character at nth position of whitespace using plsql

Tags: plsql

So I have a clob column that has more than 100,000 characters. I have to logically break the string after every nth occurrence of space and make it a new row.

Let's suppose I have to break the string after 8000 characters, and I have to break the string where there is a space between characters.

I have to logically break the string after every nth occurrence of space and make it a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need PL/SQL to read progressively through your LOB and build a new one. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION break_clob(in_clob IN clob)
  RETURN clob
AS
  var_line_length pls_integer := 8000;
  len pls_integer;
  pos pls_integer := 1;
  space pls_integer;
  newlob clob;
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(newlob, true);
  dbms_lob.open(newlob,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  
  len := LENGTH(in_clob);
  
  WHILE pos <= len
  LOOP
    space := INSTR(in_clob,' ',pos+var_line_length); -- look for first space after the next 8000 bytes
    
    IF space < 1
    THEN
      space := len;
    END IF;
    
    dbms_lob.writeappend(newlob,space-pos,dbms_lob.substr(in_clob,space-pos,pos)); -- copy the 8000 bytes + whatever to get to the next space
    
    IF space < len
    THEN
      dbms_lob.writeappend(newlob,1,CHR(10)); -- add line break
    END IF;
    
    pos := space+1; -- advance pointer to byte after the space
  END LOOP;
  
  dbms_lob.close(newlob);
  RETURN newlob;
END;
/
```

Then use the function in SQL:

```
SELECT break_clob(myclob)
  FROM table_with_clobs
```